# Slow fade out effect for slick slider

Tags: jquery, html

I created a slick slider with fadein and fadeout effect and had given auto play speed of 2 seconds. I want the fadeout effect for the images to be slow. below is my code.

HTML:

```
        <div class="slider">

      <div class="img-container"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/04/26/16/39/beach-3352363_960_720.jpg">

        </div> 

         <div class="img-container"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/04/26/16/31/marine-3352341_960_720.jpg">

        </div> 

         <div class="img-container"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/08/20/03/flag-1244649_960_720.jpg">

        </div> 

    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.slider').slick({
      dots: false,
      arrows: false,
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
  fade:true,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 2000,
      pauseOnHover:true,
      responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 767,
        settings: {
            arrows: false,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      }]
    });
  });
</script>
```

Please help me how can i do this as  i added `fadeOut:2000`
 but its not working

Codepen link:[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/dSaif/pen/ExaaQJV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This css:

```
 .slider{
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2000s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2000s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 2000s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 2000s ease-in-out;
     opacity: 1;
}
```

Add this JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider').slick({
    fade: true,
    speed: 2000,
    cssEase: 'linear'
  });
});
```

Comment: hi @ Meghna Bhuptani,  thanks for your answer. I want the fade out effect similar to this w3school link: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G0KNMPXXH2GZ

Comment: Can you please share your code of codepen or jsfiddle? @Saif

Comment: thank you @ meghna Bhuptani,  its working great. is it possible after complete fadout of one image the second will appear because at the time of fading out the two slide images mixing together. please help me on this

Comment: Can You please accept the answer is you get that? @Saif

Comment: Can you explain in brief what you are trying to say? @Saif

Comment: hi @ Meghna Bhuptani, I want to have a empty gap between each image fadout and fadein. i.e after complete fadeout of one image only the next image need to appear. please help me how can i do this. thank you soo much.

Comment: can you please help me on this

Comment: Refer this links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090788/how-to-start-fadein-and-fadeout-effect-together-in-jquery , https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/jquery-example-fadein-fadeout-and-fadetoggle/5312653019447296 @Saif

Comment: Hi @ Meghna, thanks for your response. I already tried the above given code examples but it is not as per my requirement. Your solutions of slow fade effect is working great. I just want a small delay between each slide.

Comment: Try this: continuous:0, timeout:3000 @Saif